# Microsoft Graph: Search for DriveItems on a SharePoint drive returns no results

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have files in a SharePoint Drive and want to develop a full-text search. The following call in the Graph Explorer works, finding my files either by filename or content:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{my drive id}/root/search(q='my search word')
```

The same call from my Azure hosted ASP.NET app using the `Microsoft.Graph-NuGet` package allways returns an empty list:

```
await _client
  .Drives[{my drive id}]
  .Root
  .Search({my search word})
  .Request()
  .GetAsync()
```

`_client` is an authenticated `GraphServiceClient`. For authentication, I receive a token through the Azure AD endpoint (app registered in the Azure Portal), not from the v2 Endpoint (app registered in the Application Registration Portal). To exclude this as a reason, I used the v2 Endpoint but there was no difference.

The application has the `Files.ReadWrite.All` permission scope. Receiving, saving and deleting files works fine. Only searching fails.

As a test, I gave my application all rights Graph Explorer has with no difference. I compared the URL the `GraphServiceClient` prepared but everything looked fine.

Comment: Are you using `.Search("Word")` or `.Search("'Word'")`?

Comment: The first one (exactly .Search(pattern) where pattern is a string argument). The URL, the API generates, is correct (q='my search word').

Comment: Did you tried to delete the `Search` method? As the @MarcLaFleur said, it may be you have a wrong `pattern` for the `Search` method

Comment: What do you mean with "delete the `Search` method"? My test-pattern is just a single word. And as I wrote, I checked the generated url with `_client.Drives[{my drive id}].Root.Search({my search word}).Request().GetHttpRequestMessage().RequestUri.ToString()`.

Comment: I mean that we can delete the Search method to locate it whether the problem caused by the search method.

Comment: As I wrote, looking for files, receiving the content of files, saving and deleting files works fine. Yes, the only problem is the search functionality. Can anyone confim, that search works for him in an application authenticated scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446307/does-microsoft-graph-api-search-work-when-using-app-only-token) described the same problem two days later. In a comment the author stated, it started working yesterday without him changing anything. I tested it today with my same old Code. What can I say? It works now! Looks like it was a bug on Microsofts side?

Comment: If your scenario uses "app-only" tokens there was an issue we discovered that was fixed in a recent rollout. This may explain why things appeared to start working, but we unfortunately had to temporarily disable the change so things may appear broken again. Rest assured that this is a temporary state.