# Does Microsoft Graph API /search() work when using app-only token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use the graph API (v1.0) to search for files and folders within our team's sharepoint/onedrive folders but when using an app-only token I consistently get no results for any `/search(...)` request I try.

I have an registered and application with https://apps.dev.microsoft.com and have requested and granted consent for the permissions stated in the [API Documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_search);

`User.ReadWrite.All`, `Group.Read.All`, `Sites.Read.All`, `Sites.ReadWrite.All`, `Group.ReadWrite.All`, `Sites.Manage.All`, `Files.ReadWrite.All`, `User.Read.All`, `Files.Read.All`, `Sites.FullControl.All`

When I request a token from https://login.microsoftonline.com/ I can see the granted permissions in the payload.

Using this token I can successfully access the drive and retrieve information about its contents using `drive/root`

I have a small test folder structure that contains a few simple text files.

I can confirm that this token gives me access to my files and folders by calling `drives/{driveid}/items/{folderid}/children` recursively to build a complete tree structure.

However, when I try to search the drive for filenames or text phrases that I know exist I get no results at all, no matter what combination of paths or search terms I use. I've never seen a search result from an app-only token.

Examples that I've tried;

`sites/root/drive/search(q='test')`

`drive/root/search(q='test')`

`drives/{driveid}/search(q='test')`

`drives/{driveid}/root/search(q='test')`

The phrase "test" exists both as a filename and also within the text content of some of the files.

I get an `HTTP:200` response but the value collection `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)` is always empty.

I'm building http requests in my application (Coldfusion), not using a SDK.
I wondered if I was having encoding problems so have tried various approaches of url-encoding the search part of the url `(q='test')` etc. 
I've also tried running the same requests with Postman and cUrl but the results are the same. Empty.

The only thing that works is when I try the same searches using the Graph Explorer I get the results I would expect to see.

I know that Explorer uses a different type of token so I'm wondering if this is and issues related to my token being app-only.

Does anyone know if `.../search()` actually work for app-only tokens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know if .../search() actually work for app-only tokens?

**The answer is yes, ../search() actually work for app-only tokens**

Based on my test, the following search API works well for app-only token

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root/microsoft.graph.search(q='test')

    https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveid}/root/microsoft.graph.search(q='test')

    https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveid}/microsoft.graph.search(q='test')

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drive/search(q='test')
```

For permission config, just put "**Files.Read.All, Files.ReadWrite.All, Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All**" into the GraphScopes in the project config file as [docs states](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_search).

**Above answer is based on your description：****register app in http://apps.dev.microsoft.com/**. You can ignore the SDK although it is the best choice. If you don't have a project config with GraphScopes, you need to pass the scope to auth request, it is difficult for operation.

**If your app-only mean register app in [SharePoint online](https://%3Ccompanyname%3E.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx)**, then the Graph Search API won't work. SharePoint doesn't share AccessToken with Graph directly.

Comment: I don't know why some bad guys vote down directly without testing. This answer is based on test not based on guess/suppose.

Comment: I think the answer is good Seiya. If you can also add the required scopes for App Mode permissions for each of these queries, I will upvote your answer

Comment: @DoguArslan Have update my answer. I am not sure if you want other permission except these four key permission.

Comment: @SeiyaSu Thank you for you help. I've tried your suggestions and I still get no search results. By the way where did you get `microsoft.graph.search` from? The documentation states just `search`.

I found and commented on a similar [open issue on Github](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/893) and it has now been labelled as a bug.

Comment: If you see the response, you will find the metadata query string with microsoft.graph.search. I am not sure if always, but based on the test and research, microsoft.graph.search should be the same as search.

Comment: @MattCasey I am not sure if it is bug, but it works well on my side. Maybe have some different  config or other between us.

Comment: As of today search for app-only token appears to be working correctly for me.  I ran the same search test suite this morning and got results where I never had any before. 
I'm not sure what to do now. I've asked on github is this is due to a bug being fixed or something else.  
I don't want to leave this as "magically fixed itself" as that's no help to anyone.

Comment: I agree with you. Due to the API works well on your side now, so the API itself is ok, just waiting for Product Group's feedback on your github issue. It is already not dev issue which suit StackOverflow now.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407698/microsoft-graph-search-for-driveitems-on-a-sharepoint-drive-returns-no-results) is the same question again. The answer has been commented by a microsoft developer. He confirmed, it was a bug.