# Microsoft Graph: Search for DriveItems on a drive returns all DriveItems

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I apologise in advance that this question is really a bug report but I really don't know where I should be reporting this sort of issue.

I'm using v1.0 API `/search` to find files within our drive using an app-only token using requests similar to;

```
drives/{driveid}/root/search(q='test')
```

Since 2019-04-03T18:36Z these requests are getting responses that appear to contain the entire drive full of DriveItems, files, folders, images or whatever with no relation to the search term and with an endless series of `@odata.nextLink` to the next page of useless results.

The same erroneous responses can been seen when making the same requests using the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) logged in as an individual user rather than via an app-only token.

These requests had been working perfectly for many months ([since my previous search related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446307/does-microsoft-graph-api-search-work-when-using-app-only-token))

This looks to be a bug with the indexing engine.
Any help with this issue or help with where to report this directly to MS would be most appreciated.

**UPDATE**: Omitting `/root` from the search returns the expected search results.
So:

`drives/{driveid}/search(q='test')` Works

`drives/{driveid}/root/search(q='test')` Doesn't work

This is NOT the [documented way to search a drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0) but it works.

Here's a sample good request (ID's redacted)

```
GET : drives/[[REDACTED]]/root/search(q='testfile.txt')
//HEADERS
Content-Type = application/json; charset=utf-8
Authorization = REDACTED
//BODY
{
  "$select":"id,name,file"
}
//END

RESPONSE 200 : 483ms
//HEADERS
Cache-Control = private
request-id = a4140979-8c86-41f8-b197-a1b02feb74bf
Status_Code = 200
Http_Version = HTTP/1.1
Explanation = OK
Strict-Transport-Security = max-age=31536000
Connection = close
Transfer-Encoding = chunked
Date = Wed, 03 Apr 2019 16:44:13 GMT
Content-Type = application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8
Vary = Accept-Encoding
OData-Version = 4.0
x-ms-ags-diagnostic = {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"UK South","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"4","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_1","ADSiteName":"UKS"}}
client-request-id = a4140979-8c86-41f8-b197-a1b02feb74bf
Duration = 411.1817
//BODY
{
  "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)",
  "value":[
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"testfile.txt",
      "file":{
        "mimeType":"application/octet-stream"
      }
    }
  ]
}
//END
```

And here's a sample of what the same request returns now.
As you can see the results are nonsense.

```
GET : drives/[[REDACTED]]/root/search(q='testfile.txt')
//HEADERS
Content-Type = application/json; charset=utf-8
Authorization = REDACTED
//BODY
{
  "$select":"id,name,file"
}
//END

RESPONSE 200 : 671ms
//HEADERS
Cache-Control = private
request-id = 96015ad0-3a5b-46aa-80f4-f6d6d2c903ea
Status_Code = 200
Http_Version = HTTP/1.1
Explanation = OK
Strict-Transport-Security = max-age=31536000
Connection = close
Transfer-Encoding = chunked
Date = Thu, 04 Apr 2019 08:30:11 GMT
Content-Type = application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8
Vary = Accept-Encoding
OData-Version = 4.0
x-ms-ags-diagnostic = {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"UK South","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"002","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_1","ADSiteName":"UKS"}}
client-request-id = 96015ad0-3a5b-46aa-80f4-f6d6d2c903ea
Duration = 631.8379
//BODY
{
  "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)",
  "@odata.nextLink":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/[[REDACTED]]/root/search(q='testfile.txt')?$select=id%2cname%2cfile&$skiptoken=[[REDACTED]]",
  "value":[
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Other"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Sample file"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Business Contacts"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Training"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"testfolders"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"DD"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Club"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Calendar 2019.pdf",
      "file":{
        "mimeType":"application/pdf"
      }
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Quick Start Guide.pdf",
      "file":{
        "mimeType":"application/pdf"
      }
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Onboarding.pdf",
      "file":{
        "mimeType":"application/pdf"
      }
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Offices"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Office 1"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Data"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Sprints"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Meeting Minutes"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Reports"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"IT"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"General Documentation"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Marketing"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Video demos"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Training"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Others"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Scripts"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"testfolder"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Emma"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Offices"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Offices"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Update September 2018.pdf",
      "file":{
        "mimeType":"application/pdf"
      }
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Office 2"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Office 3"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Office 4"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Office 5"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Office 6"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Meeting Minutes.pdf",
      "file":{
        "mimeType":"application/pdf"
      }
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Release Notes for Users"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
      "id":"[[REDACTED]]",
      "name":"Presentation"
    }

    And so on ...

  ]
}
//END
```

Comment: We started experiencing something similar. If we search within a folder then we are now getting all the items back no matter what the search term. If we search in the drive then the results are still correct. In other words, drives/<drive id>/microsoft.graph.search is working but drives/<drive_id>/items/<item_id>/search returns everything.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I noticed that you didn't mention using `/root` and that lead me to try omitting it from my code too.

If I request `drives/[[REDACTED]]/search(q='testfile.txt')` without the `/root` after the drive id I get decent results.

But like you I cannot search within a file system path using `:/mypath:/search(...)` which used to work before.